# Loops: Use break or state variable in constructor

Tags: c++, coding-style, standards

My friend's professor is teaching a intro C ++ course and advised against using break statements. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; input != 'Q'; i++) {
    cin >> input;
    chararray[i] = input;
}
```

is better than having an explicit if check:

```
if (input == 'Q')
    break;
```

I am not familiar with C ++ standards, but this implicit loop termination seems awkward to me coming from a Python background. Is it better to have to loop terminator in the loop constructor or in an explicit conditional block?

Comment: Normally in the header, but in the block can make it more readable. For example, if the check was supposed to be between the input and the assignment, you'll need something if you want it to match the first one. Whether that's a `break` or just an `if` around the rest of the body is a choice.

Comment: I teach that you should test in the loop header (or footer with do...while/until) as far as possible, but give up when doing this would require introducing an extra (usually Boolean) variable and/or conditionals.  But this is a matter of opinion, and opinion questions are frowned upon on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever the professor says, the loop

```
for (int i = 0; input != 'Q'; i++) {
    cin >> input;
    chararray[i] = input;
}
```

is shite! (and if the code above is written by the professor I'm happy to discuss this with said professor) The problem is that the input is used even if the input failed! You *always* need to check after reading that reading was successful, e.g.,

```
for (int i = 0; std::cin >> input && input != 'Q'; ++i) {
    chararray[i] = input;
}
```

BTW, despite the name of the language being C++, the idiomatic approach to incrementing objects is to use preincrement, i.e., to match idiomatic use the language should have been called ++C.

With respect to the actual question: I tend to not use `break;` statements to bail of loops but the loop condition. The primary reason is that I think it helps with readability. Doing so isn't always easily possible, though. Of course, I don't think people should write loops unless they are implementing a new algorithm but this is a separate topic entirely.

Comment: That code was an example from the student, so not a fault of the professor

Comment: @Timidger: I clarified the statement to not imply that I don't necessarily think it is the professor's code. Sadly, I have seen code morally equivalent to the code above in course material.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely situational. There are times which a `break` might simplify a loop. But by in large I would agree with the professor that the place the language has allotted for the loop condition should be the *only* condition for the loop... `for(; condition;)`,  `while(condition)`, etc.

Also, a better setup & loop would probably be to make `chararray` a `vector<char>` or even a `string` if applicable...

```
for(char input; std::cin >> input && input != 'Q';)
    v.push_back(input);
```

Or if an actual array is wanted, `i` should be checked to not overflow  the size of the array in the condition as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use of breaks/continues in larger more complex loops can often make the loop much harder to read for the next guy. 
As a result, if your loop has a simple predicate that can easily go into a loop condition, that is usually the best way to write it.

Also, one reason to have `if(cond)break` in the block rather than `for(...; (cond); ...)` is that you might need the test to go between things that get done, like reading a variable and using that variable, which might arguably apply in this code.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if your professor would ask the question yourself. As for your example then it contains a logical error. The first loop writes charcater '0' in chararray

```
for (int i = 0; input != 'Q'; i++) {
    cin >> input;
    chararray[i] = input;
}
```

While it seems the second loop with break does not write character '0' in the array.

```
is better than having an explicit if check:
if (input == 'Q')
    break;
```

I would use while loop. For example

```
size_t i = 0;

while ( i + 1 < N && std::cin >> input && input != '0' )
{
   chararray[i] = input;
   i++;
}

chararray[i] = '\0';
```

Or even as

```
while ( i + sizeof( '\0' ) < N && std::cin >> input && input != '0' )
```

By the way I wrote an article about false_predicate and true_predicate. Maybe it will be interesting. Though it is written in Russian it can be translated in English using for example service of google translate.

http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000066-000-0-0-1380811383